# How to achieve Anti-Aliasing in VR (Oculus Rift S and Quest)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I get rid of jagged edges in my scene, especially with UI elements?

[Image showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy20z.png)

HDRP is not supported in the oculus quest apk. I have tried the following things but neither solves my problem:

1. Quality setting anti Aliasing set tp 2X multi-sampling
2. CenterEyeAnchor Camera's rendering path to forward, turn on MSAA.

Here is the script for the scene:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class VRRenderScale : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start () 
    {
        XRSettings.eyeTextureResolutionScale = 1.5f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting Anti-Aliasing to 4x? 
Usually the Oculus plugin blocks from using Anti-Aliasing, so add this one line to your script:

`QualitySettings.antiAliasing = 2;`

Comment: tried all of these blow line of code in my script but nothing happens no difference.

 XRSettings.eyeTextureResolutionScale = 1f;
 OVRManager.tiledMultiResLevel = OVRManager.TiledMultiResLevel.LMSHigh;
 OVRManager.display.displayFrequency = 72.0f;
  QualitySettings.antiAliasing = 2;

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had faced the same issue. Try creating a material with UI/Unlit/Transparent and attach this material to your mesh/image.